# Rename Files: Remove beginning characters and add zeros to all files in a folder using Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

How do I batch rename all the files by removing all the characters, except the last group of numbers (ie `4684`, `4883`, `12650`, and `12751`), and add 5 zeros to the beginning of the file name using Mac Terminal (without installing any additional tools).  I would like to do this to all the files in a folder "$f"

Important note: these numbers are situational and will vary.

```
9edd_6500_001_000_4684.mp4
9edd_6500_001_000_4883.mp4
9edd_6500_001_000_12650.mp4
9edd_6500_001_000_12751.mp4
```

The desired outcome is to rename all the files like this...

```
000004684.mp4
000004883.mp4
0000012650.mp4
0000012751.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what's available on a 'Mac Terminal' but since the question has been tagged `bash` I'm assuming something basic like this should work:

```
for f in *.mp4
do
    echo mv "${f}" "00000${f##*_}"     # drop everything up to and including the last "_"
done
```

This prints, but does not actually execute, the following `mv` commands:

```
mv 9edd_6500_001_000_12650.mp4 0000012650.mp4
mv 9edd_6500_001_000_12751.mp4 0000012751.mp4
mv 9edd_6500_001_000_4684.mp4 000004684.mp4
mv 9edd_6500_001_000_4883.mp4 000004883.mp4
```

Once you're satisfied the `mv` commands look correct just remove the word `echo` from the code and the code will cease printing any output and instead execute the actual `mv` commands.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!